# Locking and checkout mechanism

Tags: sql-server, locking

Tables:

```
Clients (20+ fields)
  Id int,
  Name varchar,
  [State] varchar,
  Address varhcar

ClientCheckout
  ClientId
  CheckedOutAt Datetime null
```

I'm using a separate table for managing the checkout process to avoid putting any locks on the Clients table.

I need to ensure that a client can't be checked out more than once.  Once it is checked out I need to return the id of the client that was checked out.

This is what I came up with but I feel like there should be a better way

Procedure:

```
Create procedure (@state varchar(2))
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ

DECLARE @clientid INT

SELECT TOP 1
    @clientid = CustomerId
FROM ClientCheckout
WHERE CheckedOutAt IS NULL AND [state] = @state

BEGIN TRANSACTION T


    UPDATE ClientCheckout
    SET CheckedOutAt = getdate()
    WHERE ClientId = @clientid;
commit transaction t
SELECT
@clientid
```

I left the initial selection of @clientid outside of the transaction so as not to lock the Clients table.

This seems to work but it doesn't feel quite right.  Suggestions?

Comment: What does the `[state]` column indicate in the `Clients` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the `select` and `update` into a single statement that runs atomically, by doing something like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Clients
(
    ClientID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Clients
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , ClientState VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.CallCheckout
(
    ClientID INT NOT NULL
    , CheckedOutAt DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Clients(ClientState)
VALUES ('AA')
    , ('AB')
    , ('AC');

INSERT INTO dbo.CallCheckout (ClientId, CheckedOutAt)
VALUES (1, NULL);

INSERT INTO dbo.CallCheckout (ClientId, CheckedOutAt)
VALUES (2, GETDATE());

INSERT INTO dbo.CallCheckout (ClientId, CheckedOutAt)
VALUES (3, NULL);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CheckOut
(
    @state VARCHAR(3)
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP(1) dbo.CallCheckout
    SET CheckedOutAt = getdate()
    OUTPUT inserted.clientid
    FROM dbo.CallCheckout cc
        INNER JOIN dbo.Clients c ON cc.ClientID = c.ClientID
    WHERE cc.CheckedOutAt IS NULL 
        AND c.ClientState = @state;
END
GO

EXEC dbo.CheckOut 'AA';
EXEC dbo.CheckOut 'AC';
```

The results are:

[image]

Notice, I've specified the schema in the `CREATE PROCEDURE` and `UPDATE` statements.  You should always specify the schema, even if you only ever use `dbo`, since it prevents the server from having to make that decision, and potentially making the *wrong* decision.

Also, please do not use reserved keywords for column names.  I'm talking about `[state]`.  Notice, I've named that column `CheckoutState` which is not a reserved keyword, and makes the column name more meaningful.

Comment: Wouldn't this lock the clients table though?  I really don't want to do that.

Comment: The [state] or [CheckedOutState] field isn't in the checkout table.  I'd rather not duplicate it if I can avoid it.

Comment: @recursive_acronym Why is everyone so afraid of locking? You **want** locking. It's what prevents two processes from modifying the same row at the same time.

Comment: This won't lock the entire table assuming you have an index on `CheckedOutAt` and `CheckoutState`.

Comment: I do want locking, just not on the Clients table.

Comment: There is no index on [State] in the Clients table.  There is no state/checkedoutstate field in the ClientCheckout table.

Comment: I've updated my answer to move the `[state]` column into the `Clients` table.

Comment: Beautiful.   Just curious, does this put a lock on the row in the Clients table?

Comment: Not an update lock, if you aren't updating the `Clients` table.  Every row read by the server is locked, but only very momentarily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30636/discussion-between-recursive-acronym-and-max-vernon).